# In PDO mysql connection pdo query output is nothing for mysql null resultset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a login script where for database connection I am using PDO MYSQL. Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT uid,uname  from user where email_address='abc@gmail.com' AND password='".md5('abcacb')."'";
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        $stmt = $dbh->query($query);
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!$result)
            $status = FALSE;
        else
            $status = TRUE;
        $dbh = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    print $status;
```

When `email_address` & `password` both are correct `$status` is printing `1`. But if `email_address` or `password` mismatch from the database value it's not printing anything for `$status`. I assume that at least it should print `0`. But I am not getting where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When email_address & password both are correct $status is printing 1.
>   But if email_address or password is mismatch from database value it's
>   not printing any thing for $status

since you are sotring the boolean values in `$status` variable. boolean values have it's own behavior in PHP.

```
boolean value true will always print `1`
boolean value false will print nothing.
```

try this

```
echo true;
//prints 1

echo false;
//prints nothing
```

if you want 0 to be printed, then you can do it like this.

```
$status = ($result == true) ? 1 : 0;
```

above code is the ternary operator if you not aware. which is same as

```
if($result)
    $status = 1;
else
    $status = 0;
```

while using conditional statement, 1 will always be treated as boolean true and 0 as false.

i hope this answer your question.

Comment: Thanks a lots!, i was unaware of this concept. Now i got it & its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're expecting the wrong thing from print-- try using print_r or var_dump for debug printing instead.